# Record in SQL Server table causing a error - how to find the record?

Tags: sql-server, date, casting

I created a query to take the birthdate of a user and change the year to the current year (don't want to display the actual birth date)

```
CAST(
  CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) as varchar) + '-' +
  CAST(MONTH(BirthDay) as varchar) + '-' +
  CAST(DAY(BirthDay) as varchar) 
as date)
```

When I run that against my table, I get the following error:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I was able to get the query to work correctly on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0989/1)

To troubleshoot the query, I stepped through each `CAST()` function and each of them works separately.  When I change `GETDATE()` to `BirthDay`, the query works correctly, but this does not like using `GETDATE()`.  The function will run and gets through about 400 records, then returns the error message above.

Is there a way to find the actual record that is causing this problem, or is there a better way to take the Month and day of the date and make it 2013?

Comment: Is the `BirthDay` set for all users or does it contain `NULL` values as well?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes It's not set for all users, so I tried `WHERE BirthDay IS NOT NULL`, with the same result.

Comment: Is one of the birthdays Feb. 29th?  There is no 02/29/2013.  What happens if you replace `CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) as varchar)` with the hardcoded string `'2013'`?

Comment: @AdamPorad +1, hadn't thought of Feb 29th hehe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think leap year is your problem, and one of the birthday vaules is Feb. 29th during a leap year. So the error happens because there is no 02/29/2013.

To validate this hypothesis:

- What happens if you replace `CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) as varchar)` with the hardcoded string `'2013'`?
- What about if you replace it with `'2012'` which is a leap year?
- Or as Niels Keurentjes smartly suggests in the comments, just query the data to see if there's a Feb. 29th birthday `select * from Users where month(BirthDay) = 2 and day(BirthDay) = 29`

Comment: Well might as well check for sure with `select * from Users where month(BirthDay) = 2 and day(BirthDay) = 29`

Comment: That was it.  Never would have thought about that.  Thanks for the assist on that one.